# Is there any Institute clothes that allow me to use Armor?

Tags: fallout-4

I like to use faction related clothes.
I also like my armor.

For the Brotherhood of Steel, I could use the BoS Uniform.
For the minutemen, I've got the Minutemen clothes,
The Railroad doesn't seem to have any kind of uniform, so I use leather clothes/whatever "normal" clothes.

But for the Institute, all I got are various colored lab coat, that doesn't allow armor.

I ve saw on F4 wiki that there is a "Synth uniform" that would work well... But is only stealable on a companion or on two of the vendor in the Institute.

Did I miss any other choice for role-playing a Institute Sole Survivor? Or should I accept to get rid of my equipment?

Comment: Will the Institute clothes take Ballistic Weave? The higher-end versions of that mod are fairly strong - almost a replacement for armor on their own, if you don't mind perk-less "armor". (Though how anyone can really get *that* much protection from Summer Shorts is beyond me.)

Comment: Well, the goal of keeping armor is to keep perk, I ve got a almost complete set of Legendary Synth [] which improve my stealh, hacking, SVAV and lockpicking, I d rather keep them if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Synth Uniform](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Synth_uniform) is the only piece of clothing that is Institute-specific.

You can see a [listing of all the clothing](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_armor_and_clothing#Clothing) in the game on Nukapedia, including the Synth Uniform.

[X6-88](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/X6-88) has one of these in his inventory. Taking it does not require "stealing". You can freely trade items with your companions. The only possible negative consequence of doing so is them going down in a fight if you equip them poorly.

However, if you're roleplaying an Institute survivor I'm guessing you'll want to take X6-88 with you. In which case, you'll want to put armor on him, in which case you'll want him wearing the Synth Uniform. This means you'll want to buy one from the Institute vendor. You can do this as soon as you're approved to move about the Institute.

Comment: You can just ask him to give it to you? That s cool, he don t need it at all?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Assuming Shannon is correct in stating X6-88 has a Synth Uniform, he would not need it. (Nukapedia does not mention the uniform being in his inventory though, and I personally haven't progressed far enough into the game to check for myself yet.) Most companions come with two outfits - the "standard" one they're normally in when you meet them, and a "backup". X6-88's "standard" outfit is a Courser Uniform, so if he does have a Synth Uniform then it's not strictly needed by him.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Note: You will not see a companion's currently-equipped outfit in their inventory. This is an intentional design choice, and is perfectly normal. (Presumably, this is done to make it difficult for you to un-equip their clothing, which would leave the character wandering about in their undergarments.) So, any clothing you actually see in a companion's inventory is naturally going to be a "spare". To be sure, you can just look to see if it has the "equipped" marker next to it or not.

Comment: Ok, scratch what I said about Nukapedia not mentioning the Synth Uniform in X6-88's inventory. That's only half-true. The Synth Uniform page mentions you can find it there, but the inventory listing on X6-88's page doesn't have it.

Comment: @Iszi He has it. I've checked. It lets you put armor on him. Similarly, Piper has Road Leathers and Preston has a Minuteman Uniform.

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah, I figured you were right and Nukapedia needed to be updated. That's typical of practically every other clothing-wearing companion I've had so far. Though I do kind-of wonder why they bothered putting in spare clothing. It's really not necessary for the anti-nudity mechanic, and doesn't seem to add "flavor" either.

Comment: @Iszi So you can put armor on them while still having them wear clothing appropriate to their backstory and personality, I imagine.